# Trying to Add a Vlookup Piece to my Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to add a Vlookup piece to a long macro that I'm working on to eliminate some daily data manipulation work.

Essentially everyday I have four new columns of data that I compare to the day befores, using vlookup. The four new columns sit in columns C-F and the old data in columns M-P. I vlookup column D against column M, with the formula in column G.

I'm running into a problem of how to be flexible with the range I give the macro to use each day as I don't want to constantly change it. The amount of rows will fluctuate between 10,000-30,000.

Here is my code- I'm probably thinking about this all wrong.

```
Sub Lookup()

Dim i, LastRow
Set i = Sheets("data").Range("F5").End(xlUp)


If Cells(i, "F5").Value <> "" Then
Range(i, "G").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, "D"), Range("N").End(xlDown), 1, False)
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Use dynamic named range and regular VLOOKUP formula in cell. Or use VBA to mass fill in a `.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: What sort of flexibility are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It seems to me that you're over-complicating things: (1) Type into any cell the VLookup formula you want. (2) Go into the VBE direct window and type `? Selection.FormulaR1C1`. (3) Finally, put in your code `Sheets("Data").Range("F1:F30000").FormulaR1C1 = "enter here the formula you got from step 2"`. Or am I completely off?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go

```
Sub Sheet2_Button1_Click()
    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range, Mrng As Range, x

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, "G"), Cells(Rws, "G"))
    Set Mrng = Range("M1:M" & Rws)

    rng = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1, " & Mrng.Address & ",1,0),""Nope"")"

    '----------If you want it to be just values uncomment the below line--------------
    ' rng.Value=rng.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some backwards range references. I can't speak to the vlookup call, but you can start by looking at this part:

```
If Cells(i, "F5").Value <> "" Then
Range(i, "G").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, "D"), Range("N").End(xlDown), 1, False)
End If
```

Try changing it to this to fix the range declarations:

```
If Range("F" & i).Value <> "" Then
    Range("G" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("D" & i), Range("N").End(xlDown), 1, False)
End If
```